# Performance differences in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance

I have below code. Sometime it takes a bit longer time to get this code executed.
Need to improve the code.

```
//Get products from DB
DataTable dtProducts = GetAllProducts();

if(dtProducts !=null && dtProducts.Rows.Count >0)
{

dtProducts .DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
dtProducts .DefaultView.RowFilter = " product_id = '" +product_id.Trim() + "'";

DataTable dtProductCount = dtProducts .DefaultView.ToTable();

       if (dtProductCount != null && dtProductCount.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
           object obj = dtProductCount.Compute("SUM(qty)", "");
           if (!Convert.IsDBNull(obj))
           {
              int qtyProd = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
           }
       }

}
```

Is there any scope of performance improvement here ?
Like instead of **Count**, can we use **Any()**, in data table.

Comment: I'm sure the performance differences you're observing have to do with things that are out of your control, like whatever else is going on with the database at the time or the network.

Comment: Why not simply run `select sum(qty) from db_table where product_id=@product_id_param` in the first place?

Comment: I assum `GetAllProducts` queries a database, if that is the case that is what you want to focus on speeding up not an `if` statement. The difference between `Count > 0` and `Any` will probably be negligible, I suspect the compiler may even compile them down to the same code as well though I don't know for sure.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As @huMptyduMpty comments questions about improving working code are usually better suited to code review. Though make sure you check their guidelines before posting there.

Comment: If the design here is to get everything via GetAllProducts() then perform filtering on that result in the client - don't, its expensive and can have scaling issues.  Use the database itself for that, its what its designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

One definite improvement would be including the filter condition `product_id = '" +product_id.Trim() + "'` in SQL query itself in `WHERE` clause thus returning you only the required dataset instead of everything

```
select * from products
where product_id = @product_id
```

Per your comment *Because this code run inside a for each loop from where I got product Id* ... well then from your `for loop` collect all the `product_id` and create a inlist like `1,2,34,.....` then use that solely in your query using a `IN` operator.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, that was initial draft

Comment: @Rahul, Can't do as you have suggested. Because this code run inside a for each loop from where I got product Id

Comment: @Rahul, that will not work as per business logic. I need to get each product data separately qtyProd variable. There are lots of other similar logic, just shared the time consuming part.

Answer (score 1):

The database itself is specialized in data aggregation, so you could deliver that job for it:

```
public DataTable GetProductQuantitySummary(int? productId)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("...."))
    using (var cm = new SqlCommand   ("", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm.CommandText = @"
            SELECT   product_id, SUM(qty) SumQty
            FROM     Products
            WHERE    product_id = @product_id OR @product_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY product_id";
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", (object) productId ?? DBNull.Value);

        var table = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = cm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            table.Load(reader);
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

This way, you'll only return the required data.

If you prefer to call this method always passing the `productId`, you don't need to return the `DataTable` at all, and you could return the result:

```
public int GetProductQuantitySummary(int productId)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    using (var cm = new SqlCommand("", cn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cm.CommandText = @"
            SELECT   SUM(qty) SumQty
            FROM     Products
            WHERE    product_id = @product_id";
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", productId);

        return cm.ExecuteScalar() as int? ?? 0;
    }
}
```